# How to display limitedLibraryPicker in Xamarin.ios?

Tags: xamarin.ios, imagepicker

I found a solution in Swift that I tried to mimic.
But I can't figure out how to do it in Xamarin.iOS

The flow should be:

1. User clicks on a "manage access" button.
2. The user gets 3 alternatives.
3. When clicking on "select more photos", the user should be presented with the imagepicker that allows the user to give access to more photos.

How do I present the limited imagelibraryPicker?

Any answers are very much appreciated!

**The Swift code looks like this:**

```
import PhotosUI
```

@IBAction func manageButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

```
let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "",
                                    message: "Select more photos or go to Settings to allow access to all photos.",
                                    preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

let selectPhotosAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Select more photos",
                                       style: .default) { [unowned self] (_) in
    // Show limited library picker
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().presentLimitedLibraryPicker(from: self)
}
actionSheet.addAction(selectPhotosAction)

let allowFullAccessAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Allow access to all photos",
                                          style: .default) { [unowned self] (_) in
    // Open app privacy settings
    gotoAppPrivacySettings()
}
actionSheet.addAction(allowFullAccessAction)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
actionSheet.addAction(cancelAction)

present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

Comment: In Xamarin.iOS [PHPhotoLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/photos.phphotolibrary?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) class does not expose the method `presentLimitedLibraryPicker` ,feel free to raise issue here :https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues.

Comment: That explains it, thank you! Do you have any idea if I could do a workaround? Maybe use a normal libraryPicker and give the app permission to the selected photos in the future? Or do you know if there is a way to choose when the app should display the popup with "select more images/keep selection? @ColeX-MSFT

Comment: You can  implement the above code in swift , and create it into binding library ,then use in Xamarin.iOS ,check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/.